# Performance in Python 3 dictionary iteration: dict[key] vs. dict.items()

Tags: python, performance, dictionary, iteration

Which of these is faster, and why? Or are they the same? Does the answer vary by any conditions (size of dictionary, type of data, etc.)?

Traditional:

```
for key in dict:
    x = dict[key]
    x = key
```

Hipster:

```
for key, value in dict.items():
    y = value
    y = key
```

I haven't seen an exact duplicate, but if there is one I'd be happy to be pointed to it.

Comment: The "Hipster" version is more Pythonic, so I would guess that has been better optimized in the CPython interpreter, but profile and see.

Comment: @gilch That's my guess too, but I'm not sure. I would do the test myself if I had sample data, any experience doing timing, and any idea what good data sets might look like to profile edge cases / constraints.

Comment: @jpp modified the question slightly

Comment: IPython has a very convenient `%timeit` magic for this kind of profiling. You can easily make a huge dict with something like `dict(zip(range(foo), range(foo)))` for some large number foo.

Comment: The problem with "Traditional" is that it's doing an extra dict lookup every loop. This is fast, but not as fast as the `key, value` locals, I think. Although you might have to do it inside a function to see much speedup, since at the module level "locals" are just globals, which require a dict lookup.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It turns out there are actually orders of magnitude of difference.

I don't know much about performance testing, but what I tried to do was create 3 dicts of varying sizes, with each smaller dict being a subset of the larger dict. I then ran all three dicts through the two functions (Traditional vs. Hipster). Then I did that 100 times.

The dictionary sizes (number of key-value pairs) for dict1, dict2, and dict3 are 1000, 50000, 500000 respectively.

**There seems to be a significant difference, with `d.items()` being generally an order of magnitude faster**. This is in line with expectations (Python generally rewarding "pythonic" code).

Results:

```
--d[key]--
dict1 -- mean: 0.0001113555802294286, st. dev: 1.9951038526222054e-05
dict2 -- mean: 0.01669296698019025, st. dev: 0.019088713496142
dict3 -- mean: 0.2553815016898443, st. dev: 0.02778986771642094

--d.items()--
dict1 -- mean: 6.005059978633653e-05, st. dev: 1.1960199272812617e-05
dict2 -- mean: 0.00507106617995305, st. dev: 0.009871762371401046
dict3 -- mean: 0.07369932165958744, st. dev: 0.023440325168927384
```

Code ([repl.it](https://repl.it/@NotAnAmbiTurner/WhimsicalSoggyCopyrightinfringement)) providing results:

```
import timeit
import random
import statistics

def traditional(dicty):

  for key in dicty:
    x = dicty[key]
    x = key

def hipster(dicty):

  for key, value in dicty.items():
    y = value
    y = key

def generate_random_dicts():
  random_dict1, random_dict2, random_dict3 = {}, {}, {}

  for _ in range(1000):
    key = generate_random_str_one_to_ten_chars()
    val = generate_random_str_one_to_ten_chars()
    random_dict1[key] = val
    random_dict2[key] = val
    random_dict3[key] = val

  for _ in range(49000):
    key = generate_random_str_one_to_ten_chars()
    val = generate_random_str_one_to_ten_chars()
    random_dict2[key] = val
    random_dict3[key] = val

  for _ in range(450000):
    key = generate_random_str_one_to_ten_chars()
    val = generate_random_str_one_to_ten_chars()
    random_dict3[key] = val

  return [random_dict1, random_dict2, random_dict3]

def generate_random_str_one_to_ten_chars():
  ret_str = ""
  for x in range(random.randrange(1,10,1)):
    ret_str += chr(random.randrange(40,126,1))
  return ret_str

dict1, dict2, dict3 = generate_random_dicts()

test_dicts = [dict1, dict2, dict3]

times = {}
times['traditional_times'] = {}
times['hipster_times'] = {}

for _ in range(100):
  
  for itr, dictx in enumerate(test_dicts):
    start = timeit.default_timer() 
    traditional(dictx)
    end = timeit.default_timer() 
    time = end - start
    try:
      times['traditional_times'][f"dict{itr+1}"].append(time)
    except KeyError:
      times['traditional_times'][f"dict{itr+1}"] = [time]

    start = timeit.default_timer() 
    hipster(dictx)
    end = timeit.default_timer() 
    time = end - start
    try:
      times['hipster_times'][f"dict{itr+1}"].append(time)
    except KeyError:
      times['hipster_times'][f"dict{itr+1}"] = [time]

print("--d[key]--")
for x in times['traditional_times'].keys():
  ltimes = times['traditional_times'][x]
  mean = statistics.mean(ltimes)
  stdev = statistics.stdev(ltimes)
  print(f"{x} -- mean: {mean}, st. dev: {stdev}\n\n")
  
print("--d.items()--")
for x in times['hipster_times'].keys():
  ltimes = times['hipster_times'][x]
  mean = statistics.mean(ltimes)
  stdev = statistics.stdev(ltimes)
  print(f"{x} -- mean: {mean}, st. dev: {stdev}")
```

Comment: How is dict[key] way faster on smaller dictinoaries? The metrics don't support that claim.

Answer (score 9):

This code only needs to go through the dictionary once to retrieve everything from it:

```
for key, value in dict.items():
```

This code goes through the whole dictionary once, but retrieves only keys:

```
for key in dict:
    x = dict[key]
```

Then, for each key, it has to go into the dictionary again to look up the value. So, it has to be slower.

Still, the whole thing is purely academic and of no real significance in real life. When your application starts being too slow, it is really very very unlikely that the slowness will be caused by the way you iterate through a dictionary.